# MS Word 2013 change the style of the whole document when I modify the style for only a selection of text

Tags: office-2013, word-2013

When I make a change of style (Font or Paragraph) for a selection of text (example: change the font or text orientation of the selected line), Microsoft Word 2013 apply this change for the whole document in an illogical way.

To fix this issue I need to press 'redo (Ctrl-z)' and word 2013 apply the new style to the text I selected only (it's okay now) but I need to do it every time!

This process has become stressful for me and for my computer CPU especially if I edit a large document because Word 2013 change the style for the whole document.

I never had this problem with Word 2010 or 2007.

Answer (score 0):

If you are applying style from "Style" group of "Home" ribbon, then application of these styles are based on "Style type:" e.g:

```
1) Paragraph
2) Character
3) Linked (Paragraph and Character)
4) Table
5) List
```

So, it depends which type of style you are applying and by default it apply on complete target.

The easiest way to save working of CPU and eliminating the stress, is to apply format using "Font" group of "Home" ribbon and if you rapidly use same formatting on different part of document then you can use **Ctrl + Shift + C** and **Ctrl + Shift + V** command to copy only formatting of one text to another.